# Beamer metropolis theme and modifying frame footer -- extend horizontal rule across frame

Tags: beamer, footer, beamer-metropolis

Objective: Achieve something like this:

[image: Desired results]

by modifying this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.5ex depth 
\dimexpr-.5ex+0.4pt\hfill\kern0pt}

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Tag line \Vhrulefill$\begin{array} {l}\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{example-image-a}\end{array}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives this result:

[image: Starting point]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `frame footer` is only the first part of the footline in the metropolis theme. If you want your line to span the whole frame, modify the footline instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.5ex depth 
\dimexpr-.5ex+0.4pt\hfill\kern0pt}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth, sep=3ex]{footline}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    Tag line \Vhrulefill
    \space
    \includegraphics[height=0.5cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}    
    \space
    \usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]